# Given a triangle ABC and a square, explain why there exists 3 points P,Q,R on a square such that triangle ABC is similar to triangle PQR

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a triangle ABC and a square, explain why there exists 3 points P,Q,R on a square such that triangle ABC is similar to triangle PQR

How do I start this? I tried drawing the pictures but it just wasn't making sense to me.

Comment: Suppose in triangle ABC the lengths of $AB =a, BC = b, CA = c$. We can assume $a\leq b \leq c$ . From B draw a parallel line to c to construct a rectangle whose one side is c and opposite side  contains vertex B. Suppose "b" makes an angle $\alpha$ and "a" makes and angle $\beta$ to that side of rectangle which is opposite to c. As both $\alpha$ ,$\beta$ greater than zero $c >b\sin\beta = a\sin\alpha$. Extend the rectangle to that side of c which does not contain the triangle, to make it a square. You can fill rest of the logic.